# Realm + Mantle: how to avoid multiple inheritance duplication when integrating both frameworks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm, github-mantle, realm-cocoa

I have a simple scenario where I want to parse a User model from Json with Mantle and persist it to a realm database:

In order to use the Mantle library, the model interface must extend the **MTLModel** class like this:

```
@interface User: MTLModel<MTLJSONSerializing>
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *email;
@end
```

and in order to persist that model in realm, I have to declare a second interface that extends from **RLMObject**:

```
@interface RLMUser:RLMObject
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *email;
@end
```

As you see I had to implement another type of the User class because I have to extend **RLMObject**.

is there a way to avoid this kind of duplication?

Comment: Alternatively, it may be enough to conform to the `MTLModel` protocol but you would have to implement a lot of the `MTLModel` class functionality.

Comment: Thanks, that seems a proper implementation, I'll give it a try. I'll even consider dropping both frameworks and using anything else with better implemenations.

Comment: @MinaSamy Did you find using the `<MTLModel>` protocol to work? Would love to hear how it turned out

Comment: @beebcon Hi, we found that implementing the protocol for each type would take a lot of effort, we ended using the Realm-Json library, it basically adds the Mantle functionality to the the RLMObject through categories, so you end by extending a single object which is both Realm and Mantle object. https://github.com/matthewcheok/Realm-JSON

Comment: @MinaSamy Thanks, I think that's the way to go too - I notice is restricted to Realm < v1 which sucks but might be able to find a fork supporting Realm ~2.4

Comment: For those interested, I made my own fork to support modern Realm versions via `s.dependency 'Realm', '~> 2'` https://github.com/bradgmueller/Realm-JSON seems to be all good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on the idea of using the  protocol, I created a super class ([gist here](https://gist.github.com/siyu6974/0f6b8273b76ee0d7fe939e8b5a982553)):

`@interface ModelBase : RLMObject <MTLJSONSerializing, MTLModel>`

Then as @David Snabel-Caunt said, I ended up implementing some functions of the MTLModel class (copy-paste from MTLModel.m).

Finally to use it, you just need to subclass it.

Comment: Despite your solution requires lots of boilerplate, It seems there is no other way, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm, you COULD try creating a single class that inherits from both classes down a chain as long as `RLMObject` is the highest superclass (eg `User` > `MTLModel` > `RLMObject`) and seeing if that works. If `MTLModel` only works on its data through key-path values, Realm might be able to handle working with it like that.

But in all honesty, if you want to ensure that both classes behave properly as intended, it's probably best not to mix them, and simply copy the data across them when needed.

Thankfully, because `RLMObject` instances exposes all of the properties it persists through an `RLMObjectSchema` object, you don't need to manually copy each property manually, and can do it with a pretty minimal amount of code:

```
User *mantleUser = ...;
RLMUser *realmUser = ...;

// Loop through each persisted property in the Realm object and 
// copy the data from the equivalent Mantle property to it
for (RLMProperty *property in realmUser.objectSchema.properties) {
   id mantleValue = [mantleUser valueForKey:property.name];
   [realmUser setValue:mantleValue forKey:property.name];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, The multiple inheritance is not feasible, your suggestion to copy to the properties is a way better. let me ask you if there is a way to define the realm object schema itself rather than defining properties to the Realm object?